# Javascript form clears instantly and flashes one answer

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page that uses a javascript as a statistical calculator, it just needs to print the results into the text boxes i have displayed, but when i hit my submit button, the screen displays the mean value for a split second. no other fields work or stay.

My html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Script Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body class="calculator">
    <h2 class="stats">Statistical Calculator</h2>
    <p> Enter 5-20 values within 0-100 inside the box below.<br>
      Each value should be separated by one space.
    </p>
    <form>
      <textarea id="numbers" name="numberarea" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> <br> 
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="subbutton" onclick="performStatistics()" 
        value="Submit">
      <input type="reset"> 
      <br><br>
      Max: <input type="text" id ="maxnum" name="max" readonly>
      <br>
      Min: <input type="text" id="minnum" name="min" readonly>
      <br>
      Mean: <input type="text" id="meannum" name="mean" readonly>
      <br>
      Median: <input type="text" id="mednum" name="med" readonly>
      <br>
      Mode: <input type="text" id="modenum" name="mode" readonly>
      <br>
      Standard Deviation: <input type="text" id="stddev" name="std" readonly>
      <br>
      Sum: <input type="text" id="sumnum" name="sum" readonly>
      <br>
      Variance: <input type="text" id="varinum" name="vari" readonly>
      <br>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a href="../index.html" target="_self"> ePortfolio</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
function performStatistics() {
  var newarray = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
  var array = newarray.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0 || array[i] > 100) {
      alert("Enter positive values from 0-100")
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (array.length < 5 || array.length > 20) {
    alert("Enter at least 5 values & no more than 20");
    return false;
  }

  document.getElementById("meannum").value = calcMean(array);
  document.getElementById("mednum").value = calcMedian(array);
  document.getElementById("modenum").value = calcMode(array);
  document.getElementById("stddev").value = calcStdDev(array);
  document.getElementById("sumnum").value = calcSum(array);
  document.getElementById("varinum").value = calcVariance(array);
  document.getElementById("maxnum").value = findMax(array);
  document.getElementById("minnum").value = findMin(array);

  return false;
}

function calcMean(array) {
  return calcSum(array) / array.length;
}

function calcMedian(array) {
  var med = 0;
  var arraylen = array.length;
  arraylen.sort();

  if (arraylen % 2 === 0) {
    med = (array[arraylen / 2 - 1] + array[arraylen / 2]) / 2;
    //takes average of an even array
  } else {
    med = array[(arraylen - 1) / 2];
    //takes middle value of odd array
  }

  return med;
}

function calcMode(array) {
  var mode = [];
  var counter = [];
  var i;
  var holder;
  var maxfreq = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    holder = array[i];
    counter[array] = (counter[holder] || 0) + 1

    if (counter[holder] > maxfreq) {
      maxfreq = counter[holder];
    }
  }

  for (i in counter)
    if (counter.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      //returns boolean value^
      if (counter[i] === maxfreq) {
        mode.push(Number(i));
        //pushes value into (end of) array
      }
    }

  return mode;
}

function calcStdDev(array) {

  return Math.sqrt(calcVariance(array)).toFixed(2);
}

function calcSum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(array[i]);
  }
  return sum.toFixed(2);
}

function calcVariance(array) {
  var avg = calcMean(array);
  var newarray = [];
  var vari;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newarray[i] = (array[i] - avg) * (array[i] - avg);
  }

  vari = calcSum(newarray) / newarray.length;
  return vari.toFixed(2);
}

function findMax(array) {
  var newarray = array;
  var maxnum = Math.max(newarray);
  return maxnum;
}

function findMin(array) {
  var newarray = array;
  var minnum = Math.min(newarray)
  return minnum;
}
```

Comment: i apologize in advance for the format, i know its sloppy.

Comment: Do you want to submit the form or do you want to [prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) it from being submittet?

Comment: @some I would expect the form should not submit if the HTML is getting updated

Comment: By the way, you use the variable `i` multiple times, sometimes you have declared it, and sometimes you havn't. When you haven't, it is a global variable. To save yourself from troubles, put `"use strict"` as the first row of your js-file to opt in to strict mode, where variables must be declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the submit button from submitting the form.

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('subbutton').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault(); // prevent the page submit
    });
}
```

Comment: would this need to be added within the perfomStatistics function? or could it reside outside?

Comment: You place it outside

Comment: i placed that line of code and i get an error saying it cant read property 'addEventListener' of null, maybe a formatting issue?

Comment: I have updated my answer, try with the above. I think it was trying to execute addEventListener before DOM fully loaded.

Comment: so not to discredit your efforts to help me, but i just switched the input type of the submit button to "button" and that relieved that issue.

Comment: It's perfectly fine :) Yes, because by doing so you stopped the form from submitting (reloading) the web page. An input reloads the page when its of the type submit, you changed it to a button and did what the above code tried to achieve :) The important thing is that your code works as you want it to!

Comment: So now,  my issue is that only the mean field is being filled. Should i post a whole new question or edit this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `onclick` from the HTML, and add this to your script:

```
// When the DOM (HTML) is ready
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // When the form gets submitted (click on submit or enter key)
  document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    performStatistics();
    // Prevent the form from refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**Note:** your script is included in the `<head>` of your document. Waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` will ensure the document is ready no matter where your script is called. But you could skip that part if you include your script at the very bottom, before the closing `</body>` tag.